# partial differentiability and differentiability of a function at the zero point

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, differential-topology

i need to check the partial differentiability und differentiability at the zero point of the following function:

$ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \,\, with \,\, f(0)=0 \,\, and \,\, f(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}) \neq 0 $

$ f(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix})  = \frac{ x^{3} }{ \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} } $

Can you give me a hint?

I learned yesterday how to calculate the jacobian matrix of a function. Know i need to do this exercise. I am studying computer science in germany and this is an exercise of my analysis class.

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|(x,y)^T\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and note that for $(x,y)^T \neq (0,0)^T$ we have $|f((x,y)^T)| \le \|(x,y)^T\|^2$.

Use this to show that $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)^T = (0,0)^T$ with derivative $(0,0)$.

Let $h \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then
$\|f(h)-f(0)-0.h \|  \le \|h\|^2$. Hence for any $\epsilon >0$, if
$\|h\| < \epsilon$, then
$\|f(h)-f(0)-0.h \|  \le \epsilon \|h\|$. Hence $f$ is differentiable
at $0$ with derivative $0$ (that is, the zero linear functional).

Comment: Hi, i did research in books and our script from class but i still dont unterstand how i can do it like you explained. I also dont understand why you did used a norm.

Comment: How do you define differentiability?

Comment: Hi, i tried to translate it into englisch. Hope you can understand it:   Let V,W be a finite normed vector space and UcV (U is an Environment and a subset of V and V a Vectorspace). f:U->W means in x_0€U differentiable, if there exists a lieaner illustration L€Homomorphism(V,W) and a ill. R:U->W with (for all)x_0+h : f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+L(h)+R(h) and limit h->0 R(h)/||h|| = 0.
Df|x_0 := L means the derivation (or differential) of f in x_0